# Why Android LocationManager has long delay before location updates start if setting accuracy

Tags: java, android, google-maps

If I set any ACCURACY to criteria, it takes long time to LocationManager to start updating location:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);
```

If I remove ACCURACY flag, it starts immediately but sometimes not accurate.

How can I make it start updating immediately and with good accuracy?

Comment: These api's retrieve the location from a cache that all applications use. They rarely go out there and get the actual gps location. The actual gps location is triggered by "non obvious" api's. Mainly due to battery considerations.

Comment: how do you dare to note accepts jon skeet's answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, no way.

If you use `ACCURACY_FINE`, you will use GPS only, but GPS have "cold start" effect. It means that if you device not used GPS long time, it needs a lot of time for connecting with satellites and download almanac and ephemeris. You can't change this behavior.

If you don't use `ACCURACY_FINE`, you will use both GPS and network (mobile, wi-fi) signals. So you will receive quick first position from network, because they don't have "cold start" effect, but accuracy of this method is low. When your GPS module will ready, you will start receive updates from it too.

Comment: @Mike Actually there is a way: `LocationClient`.

Comment: I completely disagree with @Dimmerg. It is possible to get location from LocationManager (there is a hack). Answer posted below.

Comment: Dimmerg: I didn't say it works better, but it is what Mike asked for. Very quick but still accurate first location. It is often not as accurate as GPS. @Siddharth How can you not agree? This answer gives an explanation of how `LocationManager` works.

Answer (score 3):

If you care only about accuracy and not things like bearing or altitude I suggest switching to the new fused provider in the [`LocationClient` API from Google](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html).

It is very quick to get the first fix, more accurate than network based and doesn't depend on GPS.

It requires a bit more setup then the built-in `LocationManager`, so you may read this training article: http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Comment: I need location as soon as possible which one should i use. Accuracy is not concern for me. Which one should i use LocationManager or fused API. Please Help me on this

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that at least with `ACCURACY_FINE`, it's waiting to get an initial GPS fix. You may find that if you've already got GPS turned on for another reason (e.g. if you're in the middle of navigation) that it starts reporting immediately.

It can take a while to get a GPS fix - I think it's just a natural part of how GPS works.

Answer (score 0):

`LocationManager` is buggy on many phones, since it depends heavily on the customized android open source code for specific hardware. Samsung phones are very buggy when it comes to `LocationManager`.

You should not use `requestLocationUpdates`, instead use `getLastKnownLocation` with a small hack. Just before the `getLastKnownLocation` call put the following hack and you should be able to use a `AlarmManager` to get regular updates.

```
HomeScreen.getLocationManager().requestLocationUpdates(
    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
        }
    });
```

`LocationClient` is the other alternative to `LocationManager`. It is more accurate, uses a hello a lot less battery.

Comment: Where is this "bug" reported? I never used `getLastKnownLocation` but always `requestLocationUpdates` on Samsung phones and it works with GPS. Why would you need `AlarmManager`?

Comment: Samsung does not have any place to log bugs. They only have a forum that takes you in circles. No responses from Samsung developers at all. Here is the forum link http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=GeneralB&messageId=233508&startId=zzzzz~&searchType=TITLE&searchText=getlastknownlocation