# LocationManager delay to get GPS data

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gps

I'm having delay issues with some phones when I'm getting GPS data. The coordinates is taken when user press some fields that needs user location to validate data. Motorola phones works fine. When testing with OnePlus 3T (A3000) and LG phones the delay to get phone GPS are about 12 to 15 seconds,  no matter how provider I choose and where the user is (garage, home, office).
And no matter how many times user answer the same field.

I've read the links:

[Getting too much delay from OnLocationChange listener.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451714/getting-too-much-delay-from-onlocationchange-listener)

[Why Android LocationManager has long delay before location updates start if setting accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249080/why-android-locationmanager-has-long-delay-before-location-updates-start-if-sett)

[Location Strategies](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)

Below the code:

```
public void getLocation(final LocationListener locationListener) {
        if (locationListener == null) return;
        LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(500);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(500);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest)
                .setAlwaysShow(true);

        GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        googleApiClient.connect();
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi
                .checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());

        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
                final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
                criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
                criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
                criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
                criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        LocationManager locationManager =
                                ((LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE));

                        showError("NETWORK: "+ locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER));
                        showError("GPS: "+locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER));

                        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

                        if (App.isVersionGreaterThanLollipop()){
                            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                                    ChecklistActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                Location loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                                currentLcoation = loc;
                                showError("BEST PROVIDER: "+provider+" CURRENT LOCATION: " +loc.getLatitude()+" "+loc.getLongitude());
                                locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(
                                        criteria, locationListener, null);
                            }
                            else {
                                requestLocationPermission(locationListener);
                            }
                            ...
                        }
    ...
```

No matter if I force NETWORD_PROVIDER to get a fast location it continues to delay.

How can I get GPS data overcomming this delay?

Comment: Getting GPS fixes often involves a delay. Sometimes the delay can be indefinite (e.g., user is in a structure that blocks GPS signals, like a parking garage). This is something that you simply have to deal with. Beyond that... Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Comment: @CommonsWare I believe these fixes can be got using requestLocationUpdates, not with onRequestSingleUpdate. And on Motorola, Sony phones is almost instantaneous. I can't understand why this behavior occurs in some phones and not in others.

Comment: Different phones have different parts, including different GPS radios. GPS radios have varying quality.

Comment: Ok. So the solution is?

Comment: There is no "solution", other than to recognize that GPS fixes may be delayed or never arrive, due to environmental conditions. Your app needs to be able to cope with that. This is not significantly different from other situations that your app might need to be able to address (e.g., no connectivity from an app that wants to talk to a server).